# Как увеличить скорость падения фигуры в Тетрис?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, canvas

Нужно реализовать увеличение скорости падения фигуры с каждым убранным уровнем. Кажется уже всё перепробовал, уже глаза замылились. Кто поможет, тому буду безмерно благодарен.

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("tetris");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.scale(20, 20);
  let makeMatrix = function(w, h) {
    const matrix = [];
    while (h--) {
      matrix.push(new Array(w).fill(0));
    }
    return matrix;
  };

  let makePiece = function(type) {
    if (type === "i") {
      return [
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0]
      ];
    } else if (type === "j") {
      return [
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [2, 2, 0]
      ];
    } else if (type === "l") {
      return [
        [0, 3, 0],
        [0, 3, 0],
        [0, 3, 3]
      ];
    } else if (type === "o") {
      return [
        [4, 4],
        [4, 4]
      ];
    } else if (type === "s") {
      return [
        [0, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ];
    } else if (type === "t") {
      return [
        [0, 6, 0],
        [6, 6, 6],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ];
    } else if (type === "z") {
      return [
        [7, 7, 0],
        [0, 7, 7],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ];
    }
  };

  let points = function() {
    let rowCount = 1;
    outer: for (let y = area.length - 1; y > 0; --y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < area[y].length; ++x) {
        if (area[y][x] === 0) {
          continue outer;
        }
      }
      const row = area.splice(y, 1)[0].fill(0);
      area.unshift(row);
      ++y;
      player.score += rowCount;
    }
  }
  let collide = function(area, player) {
    const [m, o] = [player.matrix, player.pos];
    for (let y = 0; y < m.length; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < m[y].length; ++x) {
        if (m[y][x] !== 0 && (area[y + o.y] && area[y + o.y][x + o.x]) !== 0) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
  let drawMatrix = function(matrix, offset) {
    matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
      row.forEach((value, x) => {
        if (value !== 0) {
          let imgTag = document.createElement("IMG");
          imgTag.src = colors[value];
          context.drawImage(imgTag, x + offset.x, y + offset.y, 1, 1);
        }
      });
    });
  };
  let merge = function(area, player) {
    player.matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
      row.forEach((value, x) => {
        if (value !== 0) {
          area[y + player.pos.y][x + player.pos.x] = value;
        }
      });
    });
  };
  let rotate = function(matrix, dir) {
    for (let y = 0; y < matrix.length; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < y; ++x) {
        [
          matrix[x][y],
          matrix[y][x]
        ] = [
          matrix[y][x],
          matrix[x][y],
        ]
      }
    }
    if (dir > 0) {
      matrix.forEach(row => row.reverse());
    } else {
      matrix.reverse();
    }
  };
  let playerReset = function() {
    const pieces = "ijlostz";
    player.matrix = makePiece(pieces[Math.floor(Math.random() * pieces.length)]);
    player.pos.y = 0;
    player.pos.x = (Math.floor(area[0].length / 2)) - (Math.floor(player.matrix[0].length / 2));
    if (collide(area, player)) {
      area.forEach(row => row.fill(0));
      player.score = 0;
      gameRun = false;
    }
  };
  let playerDrop = function() {
    player.pos.y++;
    if (collide(area, player)) {
      player.pos.y--;
      merge(area, player);
      points();
      playerReset();
    }
  };
  let playerMove = function(dir) {
    player.pos.x += dir;
    if (collide(area, player)) {
      player.pos.x -= dir;
    }
  };
  let playerRotate = function(dir) {
    const pos = player.pos.x;
    let offset = 1;
    rotate(player.matrix, dir);
    while (collide(area, player)) {
      player.pos.x += offset;
      offset = -(offset + (offset > 0 ? 1 : -1));
      if (offset > player.matrix[0].length) {
        rotate(player.matrix, -dir);
        player.pos.x = pos;
        return;
      }
    }
  };
  let draw = function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    updateScore();
    drawMatrix(area, {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    });
    drawMatrix(player.matrix, player.pos);
  };
  let dropInter = 100;
  let time = 0;
  let update = function() {
    time++;
    if (time >= dropInter) {
      playerDrop();
      time = 0;
    }
    draw();
  };
  let updateScore = function() {
    context.font = "bold 1px Arial";
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.textAlign = "left";
    context.textBaseline = "top";
    context.fillText("Lines:" + player.score, 0.1, 0.1);
  };
  // let addSpeed = function() {
  //  if (updateScore > 0) {
  //   dropInter -= 5;
  //  }
  // };
  // addSpeed();
  let gameOver = function() {
    clearInterval(gameLoop);
    context.font = "2px Arial";
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.textBaseline = "middle";
    context.fillText("GAME OVER", (canvas.width / 20) / 2, (canvas.width / 20) / 2);
    document.getElementById("start_game").disabled = false;
  };
  const colors = [
    null,
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAABASURBVFhH7dcxEQAgDATBgBpkRiZugBnQQJq96tNtm7ZOUdgF5Hjn53JGf7MsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIDi9zxiA/4+DjI3K6uXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAABFSURBVFhH7dehEQAgDATBh5ZoAEvF2DRATcAwqYE3d+rj1qbsm4w9QB8rz7/FbKq5bQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADm91w6cr4PMmFrragAAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAABGSURBVFhH7dcxEQAgDATBB3FowAs1XqIBc8Aw0cA3d9Wn2zZl32TsAdboef6tzVDNbQsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwv+fSAYyGDzIDc/xyAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAIAAAGLH901AAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAa0lEQVR4nGP5//8/AwywAPGy01YIDooMgoOiB66BoB5kldhVUSiB7C4UCaw2U9lyKkrgCiuSTRrVQJEGXOkJpwaSYi3K9Nhg9PSohlENODSQWi6RBMjJDqSCUQtGLRi1YNSCEWMBsFClnQUAHyUliPhfuZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAABESURBVFhH7dcxEQAgDATBB3lYAHnEAvaAYaKBb+6qT7dtyr7J2APMFnn+bayumtsWAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYH7PpQOPVg8yEVQxkwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAABFSURBVFhH7dehEQAgDATBhxLwSPovCBlPC8AwqYE3d+rj1qbsm4w9wOojz7+1mKq5bQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADm91w6YO4PMgLP8KUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAABCSURBVFhH7dcxEQAgDATBgAHc4L/GDQqAGdBAmr3q022bsk6R2AWM9s7P9Rn1zbQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJLf84gNFUUOMkwQM24AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
  ];
  const area = makeMatrix(14, 22);
  const player = {
    pos: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    matrix: null,
    score: 0
  };
  const move = 1;
  let gameLoop;
  let gameRun = false;
  playerReset();
  draw();
  gameOver();
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
      playerMove(-move);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
      playerMove(+move);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      playerRotate(-move);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      playerDrop();
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("start_game").onclick = function() {
    gameRun = true;
    playerReset();
    let t = 10;
    gameLoop = setInterval(function() {
      if (gameRun) {
        update();
      } else {
        gameOver();
      }
    }, t);
    this.disabled = false;
  };
})();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #737373;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.canvas_wrap {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.canvas_wrap>* {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.canvas_wrap>button {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  outline: none;
}

.canvas_wrap>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Tetris</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAIAAAGLH901AAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAa0lEQVR4nGP5//8/AwywAPGy01YIDooMgoOiB66BoB5kldhVUSiB7C4UCaw2U9lyKkrgCiuSTRrVQJEGXOkJpwaSYi3K9Nhg9PSohlENODSQWi6RBMjJDqSCUQtGLRi1YNSCEWMBsFClnQUAHyUliPhfuZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="canvas_wrap">
    <canvas id="tetris" width="280" height="440"></canvas>
    <button type="button" id="start_game">Start</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dropInter = Math.max(dropInter - 5, 20);
```

Имеет смысл рассмотреть вариант с переменным декрементом - уменьшающимся вместе с значением `dropInter`.

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("tetris");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.scale(20, 20);
  let makeMatrix = function(w, h) {
    const matrix = [];
    while (h--) {
      matrix.push(new Array(w).fill(0));
    }
    return matrix;
  };

  let makePiece = function(type) {
    if (type === "i") {
      return [
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0]
      ];
    } else if (type === "j") {
      return [
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [2, 2, 0]
      ];
    } else if (type === "l") {
      return [
        [0, 3, 0],
        [0, 3, 0],
        [0, 3, 3]
      ];
    } else if (type === "o") {
      return [
        [4, 4],
        [4, 4]
      ];
    } else if (type === "s") {
      return [
        [0, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ];
    } else if (type === "t") {
      return [
        [0, 6, 0],
        [6, 6, 6],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ];
    } else if (type === "z") {
      return [
        [7, 7, 0],
        [0, 7, 7],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ];
    }
  };

  let points = function() {
    let rowCount = 1;
    outer: for (let y = area.length - 1; y > 0; --y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < area[y].length; ++x) {
        if (area[y][x] === 0) {
          continue outer;
        }
      }
      const row = area.splice(y, 1)[0].fill(0);
      area.unshift(row);
/* *** */
dropInter = Math.max(dropInter - 10, 5);
console.log("dropInter =", dropInter);
      ++y;
      player.score += rowCount;
    }
  }
  let collide = function(area, player) {
    const [m, o] = [player.matrix, player.pos];
    for (let y = 0; y < m.length; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < m[y].length; ++x) {
        if (m[y][x] !== 0 && (area[y + o.y] && area[y + o.y][x + o.x]) !== 0) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
  let drawMatrix = function(matrix, offset) {
    matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
      row.forEach((value, x) => {
        if (value !== 0) {
          let imgTag = document.createElement("IMG");
          imgTag.src = colors[value];
          context.drawImage(imgTag, x + offset.x, y + offset.y, 1, 1);
        }
      });
    });
  };
  let merge = function(area, player) {
    player.matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
      row.forEach((value, x) => {
        if (value !== 0) {
          area[y + player.pos.y][x + player.pos.x] = value;
        }
      });
    });
  };
  let rotate = function(matrix, dir) {
    for (let y = 0; y < matrix.length; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < y; ++x) {
        [
          matrix[x][y],
          matrix[y][x]
        ] = [
          matrix[y][x],
          matrix[x][y],
        ]
      }
    }
    if (dir > 0) {
      matrix.forEach(row => row.reverse());
    } else {
      matrix.reverse();
    }
  };
  let playerReset = function() {
    const pieces = "ijlostz";
    player.matrix = makePiece(pieces[Math.floor(Math.random() * pieces.length)]);
    player.pos.y = 0;
    player.pos.x = (Math.floor(area[0].length / 2)) - (Math.floor(player.matrix[0].length / 2));
    if (collide(area, player)) {
      area.forEach(row => row.fill(0));
      player.score = 0;
      gameRun = false;
    }
  };
  let playerDrop = function() {
    player.pos.y++;
    if (collide(area, player)) {
      player.pos.y--;
      merge(area, player);
      points();
      playerReset();
    }
  };
  let playerMove = function(dir) {
    player.pos.x += dir;
    if (collide(area, player)) {
      player.pos.x -= dir;
    }
  };
  let playerRotate = function(dir) {
    const pos = player.pos.x;
    let offset = 1;
    rotate(player.matrix, dir);
    while (collide(area, player)) {
      player.pos.x += offset;
      offset = -(offset + (offset > 0 ? 1 : -1));
      if (offset > player.matrix[0].length) {
        rotate(player.matrix, -dir);
        player.pos.x = pos;
        return;
      }
    }
  };
  let draw = function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    updateScore();
    drawMatrix(area, {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    });
    drawMatrix(player.matrix, player.pos);
  };
  let dropInter = 100;
  let time = 0;
  let update = function() {
    time++;
    if (time >= dropInter) {
      playerDrop();
      time = 0;
    }
    draw();
  };
  let updateScore = function() {
    context.font = "bold 1px Arial";
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.textAlign = "left";
    context.textBaseline = "top";
    context.fillText("Lines:" + player.score, 0.1, 0.1);
  };
  // let addSpeed = function() {
  //  if (updateScore > 0) {
  //   dropInter -= 5;
  //  }
  // };
  // addSpeed();
  let gameOver = function() {
    clearInterval(gameLoop);
    context.font = "2px Arial";
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.textBaseline = "middle";
    context.fillText("GAME OVER", (canvas.width / 20) / 2, (canvas.width / 20) / 2);
    document.getElementById("start_game").disabled = false;
  };
  const colors = [
    null,
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAABASURBVFhH7dcxEQAgDATBgBpkRiZugBnQQJq96tNtm7ZOUdgF5Hjn53JGf7MsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIDi9zxiA/4+DjI3K6uXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAABFSURBVFhH7dehEQAgDATBh5ZoAEvF2DRATcAwqYE3d+rj1qbsm4w9QB8rz7/FbKq5bQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADm91w6cr4PMmFrragAAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAABGSURBVFhH7dcxEQAgDATBB3FowAs1XqIBc8Aw0cA3d9Wn2zZl32TsAdboef6tzVDNbQsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwv+fSAYyGDzIDc/xyAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAIAAAGLH901AAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAa0lEQVR4nGP5//8/AwywAPGy01YIDooMgoOiB66BoB5kldhVUSiB7C4UCaw2U9lyKkrgCiuSTRrVQJEGXOkJpwaSYi3K9Nhg9PSohlENODSQWi6RBMjJDqSCUQtGLRi1YNSCEWMBsFClnQUAHyUliPhfuZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAABESURBVFhH7dcxEQAgDATBB3lYAHnEAvaAYaKBb+6qT7dtyr7J2APMFnn+bayumtsWAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYH7PpQOPVg8yEVQxkwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAABFSURBVFhH7dehEQAgDATBhxLwSPovCBlPC8AwqYE3d+rj1qbsm4w9wOojz7+1mKq5bQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADm91w6YO4PMgLP8KUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAABCSURBVFhH7dcxEQAgDATBgAHc4L/GDQqAGdBAmr3q022bsk6R2AWM9s7P9Rn1zbQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJLf84gNFUUOMkwQM24AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
  ];
  const area = makeMatrix(14, 22);
  const player = {
    pos: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    matrix: null,
    score: 0
  };
  const move = 1;
  let gameLoop;
  let gameRun = false;
  playerReset();
  draw();
  gameOver();
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
      playerMove(-move);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
      playerMove(+move);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      playerRotate(-move);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      playerDrop();
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("start_game").onclick = function() {
    gameRun = true;
    playerReset();
    let t = 10;
    gameLoop = setInterval(function() {
      if (gameRun) {
        update();
      } else {
        gameOver();
      }
    }, t);
    this.disabled = false;
  };
})();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #737373;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.canvas_wrap {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.canvas_wrap>* {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.canvas_wrap>button {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  outline: none;
}

.canvas_wrap>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Tetris</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAIAAAGLH901AAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAa0lEQVR4nGP5//8/AwywAPGy01YIDooMgoOiB66BoB5kldhVUSiB7C4UCaw2U9lyKkrgCiuSTRrVQJEGXOkJpwaSYi3K9Nhg9PSohlENODSQWi6RBMjJDqSCUQtGLRi1YNSCEWMBsFClnQUAHyUliPhfuZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="canvas_wrap">
    <canvas id="tetris" width="280" height="440"></canvas>
    <button type="button" id="start_game">Start</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: почему-то не работает(

Comment: у меня все работает

Comment: теперь всё работает) Я понимал, что нужно декрементировать dropInter, но не знал как сделать это правильно. Спасибо.